# How to resolve an issue with HiddenFor() when 2nd post occurs in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've seen the same problem in other pages, but the solutions didn't work for my project. ModelState didn't not work.

Model:

```
public class LoadInvoiceModel
{
    public LoadInvoiceModel()
    {
        RecivedProducts = new List<ProductInput>();

        Transmitter = new Transmitter();
        Reciver = new Reciver();
        Obverse = new Obverse();
        Concepts = new List<Concept>();
        Taxes = new List<Tax>();
    }

    // general info
    public int SineliId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Orden de Compra")]
    public int PurchaseOrderId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No de Entrada")]
    public string ProductsInputFolio { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ProductsInputDate { get; set; }

    public string ReceptionStore { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public Decimal ConceptTotal { get; set; }

    // recived products
    public IList<ProductInput> RecivedProducts { get; set; }

    // invoice data extracted from xml file
    public string FilenameXml { get; set; }
    public string FilenamePdf { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Fecha de emisíon")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BroadcastDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Impuesto")]
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descuento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Serie")]
    public string Serie { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Folio")]
    public string Folio { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Pago")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FechaPago { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Subtotal")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Subtotal { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Total")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Forma de Pago")]
    public string FormaPago { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "No de Certificado")]
    public string NoCertificado { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Comprobante")]
    public string TipoComprobante { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Condiciones de pago")]
    public string CondicionesPago { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Cambio")]
    public decimal TipoCambio { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Moneda")]
    public string Moneda { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Numero de Cuenta de Pago")]
    public string NumeroCuentaPago { get; set; }

    public Transmitter Transmitter { get; set; }
    public Reciver Reciver { get; set; }
    public List<Concept> Concepts { get; set; }
    public List<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
    public Obverse Obverse { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class CreditNoteController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult LoadCreditNote(string parameters) 
    {

        var supplier = _workContext.CurrentSupplier;
        var model = new LoadCreditNoteModel();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters))
            return View("PendingCreditNotes");

        var array = parameters.Split(',')
            .Select(x => { return int.Parse(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? x : "0"); })
            .ToArray();

        model.Requests = _creditNoteService.GetCreditNotesFromArray(supplier.SineliId, array)
            .Select(x => {
                return new LoadCreditNoteModel.Request()
                {
                    SineliId = x.Id,
                    Type = x.Type,
                    Application = x.Application,
                    AccreditanceDate = x.AccreditanceDate,
                    ConceptTotal = x.Total
                };
            }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [HttpParamAction]
    public ActionResult AddCreditNoteXmlFile(LoadCreditNoteModel model, HttpPostedFileBase xmlFile)
    {
        var supplier = _workContext.CurrentSupplier;

        if (xmlFile == null || xmlFile.ContentLength <= 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "El archivo no pudo ser leído, verifique que el documento este en el formato correcto");
            return View("LoadInvoice", model);
        }

        var stream = new StreamReader(xmlFile.InputStream,Encoding.UTF8);

        string xml = RemoveTroublesomeCharacters(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stream.ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8));

        //string xml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stream.ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8);

        //string unicode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stream.ReadToEnd(), Encoding.UTF8);
        //byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(unicode);
        //string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

        var invoice = GetInvoiceFromXML(xml);
        invoice.FilenameXml = xmlFile.FileName;


        if (supplier.Rfc.Trim() != invoice.Transmitter.Rfc)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format("Su archivo XML indica que el RFC es {0}. El RFC asociado con su usuario es {1} " +
                "por favor verifique que este subiendo la factura correspondiente",
                invoice.Reciver.Rfc, supplier.Rfc));
            return View("LoadCreditNote", model);
        }

        if (!_invoiceService.IsInvoiceXmlValid(xml))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "El documento XML no ha pasado la verificación del SAT, " +
                "revise la validez del documento o comuníquese con el departamento de Facturacion de Elizondo");
            return View("LocaCreditNote", model);
        }


        if (invoice.Obverse.UuId == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "La Factura no tiene timbre fiscal");
            return View("LoadCreditNote", model);
        }

        model.Invoices.Add(invoice);

        model.Documents.Add(new LoadCreditNoteModel.Document() { Uuid = invoice.Obverse.UuId });

        ModelState.Clear();


        return View("LoadCreditNote", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [HttpParamAction]
    public ActionResult AddCreditNotePdfFile(LoadCreditNoteModel model, HttpPostedFileBase pdfFile)
    {

        var document = model.Documents.Where(d => d.Selected == true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (document == null)
            return View("LoadCreditNote", model);

        var invoice = model.Invoices.Where(i => i.Obverse.UuId == document.Uuid).FirstOrDefault();
        invoice.FilenamePdf = pdfFile.FileName;
        Session["fileNamePDF"]=pdfFile.FileName;

        using(var reader = new BinaryReader(pdfFile.InputStream))
            Session[string.Format("pdf-{0}", document.Uuid)] = reader.ReadBytes(pdfFile.ContentLength);

        ModelState.Clear();
        return View("LoadCreditNote", model);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

View:

```
@model LoadCreditNoteModel
               <section class="mainSection">
            <div class="xml" id="btnAddXml">
                <p>AGREGAR XML</p>
            </div>
        </li>

               <li>
                <div class="pdf-button pdf" id="btnAddPdf">
                    <p>AGREGAR PDF</p>
                </div>    
            </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
<fieldset>
                                @if (Model.Invoices[0].Taxes.Count >= 1)
                                { 
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Taxes.FirstOrDefault().Name) &nbsp;
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Taxes.FirstOrDefault().Rate)%
                                </label>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Taxes.FirstOrDefault().Name)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Taxes.FirstOrDefault().Rate)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Taxes.FirstOrDefault().Amount)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Taxes.FirstOrDefault().Amount)
                            </td>
                                }
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Discount)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Discount)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Discount)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Total)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Total)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Invoices[0].Total)
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                </div>
            }
        }

</fieldset>
}
```

When the user uploads an XML, the page does a POST to read the document and show it on display, additionally the user uploads PDF file (necessary to save) and here is the problem, the page does other POST and the lists(collections) of Taxes and Concepts is NULL in my model. The other elements stay in the model correctly.

Comment: You have far too much code here. Narrow it down to indicate what the specific issue is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When the user uploads an XML, the page does a  first POST to read the document and show it on display, additionally the user uploads PDF file (necessary to save) and here is the problem, the page does the second POST and the lists(collections) of Taxes and Concepts is NULL in my model. The other elements stay in the model correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the page does other POST and the lists(collections) of Taxes and Concepts is NULL in my model

The 'lists' will be null as there a no lists inside the `@Html.BeginForm`.

MVC is stateless so your POST only gets what is inside the `<form>` tags for the POST, it doesn't know about anything in either the original GET or any previous POSTS.

You'll need to reload the reference data in the POST action.